# How to access devise helpers if devise is loaded in a rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-engines

I was wondering if I could access devise helpers from a parent application if devise is loaded in a rails engine. (helpers such as `current_user`, or `authenticate_user!`).

I was considering mounting my core application in a mountable engine - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-devise-inside-a-mountable-engine

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?